# How to disable all Windows 10 spying features?

Tags: windows-10

Lately, there have been a lot of reports on how Windows 10 spies on you. It seems that Windows 10 automatically [collects a lot of information in the background and sends them to Microsoft](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/08/even-when-told-not-to-windows-10-just-cant-stop-talking-to-microsoft/), those information even include your [keyboard typing data, your microphone data, your webcam data](http://localghost.org/posts/a-traffic-analysis-of-windows-10), etc.

This is a privacy nightmare. What are the steps that I can take to completely or mostly disable all of these information gathering features of Windows 10? What programs do I have to use, registry keys I have to modify, group policies I have to change, etc.?

Comment: There are numerous programs that will disable the Windows 10 "spying" features.  Which programs have you tried but ruled out?  This cannot be done without a third-party tool, outside of the controls provides to disable those features of course, which I assume based on the way this question is being ask isn't enough or isn't considered to actually disable these features fully ( even though that is exactly what happens ).  The privacy issues are being over reported and fear mongering is happening by the uninformed.

Comment: That question doesn't have an answer yet but here is the useful link from @DavidPostill: [Everything You Need to Disable in Windows 10](http://windows.wonderhowto.com/inspiration/everything-you-need-disable-windows-10-0163552/)

Comment: Registry settings for all 'public' privacy settings can be found in my PowerShell script: [Set-Privacy.ps1](https://github.com/hahndorf/Set-Privacy)

Comment: [Software solution here](http://wintoflash.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=42295)

Comment: The only ways to know for sure that you have stopped the spying are: keep permanently disconnected from network, replace operating system with a more trusted operating system.

Comment: Hi Chin,

Since I started to use Windows 10 in the network I am member in all have discussed and prefered this tool https://github.com/Nummer/Destroy-Windows-10-Spying/releases


(The program put lots of different IP:adresses in example: C:\windows\system32\etc\hosts You can also read more in the github in description of the tool Cheers
Cheers // Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Simply do not use you Microsoft ID in your Windows, rather use an **Offline account** so that your information is not sent to the Microsoft server. You can also turn off the Privacy> Activity History **Send my activity history to Microsoft** for more assurance.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate Windows Tweaker has made a program to do this since Windows Vista:
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-4-windows-10

Go to UWT's privacy section, and it can automate all commonly known lock-downs. Note, there are a few things it still wont lock out 100%, such as blocking access to ports on your computer, or shutting down core networking services... but it will get you to a stage that would be temporarily more-secure than probably most of your other technology devices are.